# How can you prevent Proguard from removing a Kotlin object definition?

Tags: kotlin, proguard

```kotlin
@Serializable(with = TokenResponseSerializer::class)
sealed class TokenResponse {
    @Serializable
    data class Success(
        @SerialName("access_token")
        val accessToken: String,
        @SerialName("refresh_token")
        val refreshToken: String? = null,
        @SerialName("id_token")
        val idToken: String,
        val scope: String,
        @SerialName("expires_in")
        val expiresIn: Int,
        @SerialName("token_type")
        val tokenType: String,
    ) : TokenResponse()

    @Serializable
    data class Error(
        val error: String,
        @SerialName("error_description")
        val errorDescription: String,
    ) : TokenResponse()
}

object TokenResponseSerializer : JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer<TokenResponse>(TokenResponse::class) {
    override fun selectDeserializer(element: JsonElement) = when {
        "error" in element.jsonObject -> TokenResponse.Error.serializer()
        else -> TokenResponse.Success.serializer()
    }
}
```

The following works:

```
-keep class package.auth.** { *; }
```

Except this also accidentally keeps another class in the auth package.

The following doesn't work:

```
-keep class package.auth.TokenResponse { *; }
-keep class package.auth.TokenResponse.* { *; }
-keep class package.auth.TokenResponseSerializer { *; }
```

How can I write this in a way that only keeps the desired classes?

Comment: And what will be if you add also: `-keep class package.auth.TokenResponseSerializer.* { *; }`? Inside the `TokenResponseSerializer` should be also an instance field and object getter.